# Custom menu walker to generate integrated breadcrumb dropdowns

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, breadcrumbs

Have been trying to write a custom walker class which returns a wp_custom_menu as follows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC5cP.png

Planning to enhance the different states with some scripting. The page at http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/169/jQuery-Plugin-xBreadcrumbs-Extended-Breadcrumbs-navigation is a good example of the planned end result.

Could not find any leads nor howtos, some ideas would be fabulous!

Many thanks,

F.

Comment: Also posted here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17290/custom-walker-to-generate-menu-with-integrated-breadcrumb-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Did you review this tutorial:

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output